# How do make an external API call from a Podio App field?

Tags: podio

I have a location field called origin and a field called distination. I am trying to calculate a third field called distance by using an address from both the Origin and the Destination field? What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Here's one idea. Use the Google map's destination API to get the distance between between the 2 location fields. I am not sure how I can make these 2 API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a third party tool to calculate the distance. Then update a number field (or maybe text field depending on your need) in Podio with the result. The calculation field cannot be use for such purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, but I don't think that's currently possible within Podio. I tried to get this to work using Podio's Calculation field and [Google's Distance Matrix service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix). Unfortunately, the Calculation field doesn't allow access to the XMLHttpRequest API, which is what you would likely need to access any 3rd-Party APIs.

[image: Not defined]